# AddEvenLister fires off immediately after being attached

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

I want to know how to correctly add an Event Listener like onClick to a dynamic div. Here’s my snippet:

```
var $menu = new Array(2);
createDiv('yes');    

function createDiv(title) {

var $class = 'menuLink';
var $title = 'title';

for(var i=0; i<$menu.length;i++)
{
   $title = 'title';
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
   newdiv.setAttribute('class', $class);
   newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'item'+i);

   newdiv.addEventListener('onclick', clickHandle(newdiv.id),false);

   if (title) 
   {
     newdiv.innerHTML = $title;
   } else {
 newdiv.innerHTML = "No Title";
   }

   document.getElementById('menu').appendChild(newdiv);
   showMenu();   
 }
} 

function clickHandle(e)
{
if(e == 'item0')
{
    alert('Link is' + ' ' + e);
}else{
    alert('Another Link');
}
}
```

Here's my problem, the snippet works fine, It creates my divs, adds id's values and all, but the event fires off as soon as the event is attached, so while the for loop is creating the divs the alert window says: Link is item0, and immediately after this it says:  Another Link.

Am I misunderstanding this? (I used this method zillions of times in AS3 with the expected result, just attached a function waiting for a click). What I want is that my Divs wait for the user to click on them, not to fire off immediately after of being attached. Thanks for any hint on this one. Greetings.

Ps. IE doesn't support addEventListener, but I want to resolve this before cross to the IE sea of madness, but I will appreciate the IE approach as well.
- I tried "onclick" and just 'click' into the addEventListener line, both with the same result described above.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
newdiv.addEventListener('onclick', clickHandle(newdiv.id),false);
```

with

```
(function(newdiv){
    newdiv.addEventListener('onclick', clickHandle(newdiv.id), false);
 })(newdiv);
```

The event wasn't triggered but you were calling `clickHandle(newdiv.id)` and passing the result of this call to `addEventListener`. Note also that the name of the event is `'click'`, not `'onclick'`.
Additionally, the variable newdiv was changed by the following loop. That's why I suggest to enclose it in a closure to prevent its variations.

You may also use this :

```
(function(newdiv){
   newdiv.onclick = function(){clickHandle(newdiv.id)};
})(newdiv);
```

Comment: Hi @dystroy, well no result so far. Your 1st and 2nd approach applied the onclick to the menu items(divs) but when I click on one of this divs all of them alert 'Item6' (Which is the number of divs/buttons that I need and have being dynamically created). The last one is jQuery and I want to understand how to built this using js first. I used an array approach but its results it's the same of your both suggestion: after I click a Div its Id is item6. This is the addition: newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'item'+i);  $menu.push(newdiv); $menu[i].onclick = function(){clickHandle(newdiv.id)}; thanks man.

Comment: @Diego See edit. My solutions encloses the value of newdiv at time of iteration in a closure so that it doesn't change.

Comment: you are da man @dystroy. It works like a charm. Man just a little question, I can't get this implementation (I learned some coding from AS3 where functions within functions were almost banned, since the problem of using them out of their scope). So that concept of encloures is really useful now that js is back. What’s that deal to put within parenthesis the function? what does it does? and why the line does it have the last (newdiv)?. Man thanks for some aside notes in order to really get how this great line does work. Man anyway thanks a LOT!. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

since you already use jquery why not use it on your event binding?

Its cross-browser-compatible so you don't have to worry about IE anymore

try
.click();

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Why do you think he is using jQuery?

Comment: Nop man, I'm not using jQuery. I just like to declarate variables with the $ sign, It's just a way that I like. Thanks man, I'm moving from As3 to Js so I want to stick as much as I can to js in order to get used to it before moving to use libraries.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just gave it a quick answer this morning and your $ signs got me thinking :-)

Comment: @TomKossmann Oh no man, don't worries, Any help is more than appreciated. Greetings.